Refer to first and last page of each included PDF – Blank page on top
I am referring to this question.
I would like to do the same, but adding a blank page before beginning the inclusion of PDFs in the document.
I use the following command in the preamble to insert a blank page:
\usepackage{afterpage}
\newcommand\blankpage{
\null
\thispagestyle{empty}
\clearpage
}

and then, taking inspiration from this answer, I use the following MWE:
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{afterpage}
\newcommand\blankpage{
\null
\thispagestyle{empty}
\clearpage
}

\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\AM@output@i{\setboolean{AM@endoflist}{false}}
{\newpage
  \label{start-\AM@currentdocname}%
  \setboolean{AM@endoflist}{false}}
{}{\fail}

\patchcmd\AM@output@i{\global\let\@deferlist\AM@deferlist}
{\global\let\@deferlist\AM@deferlist
  \label{stop-\AM@currentdocname}}
{}{\fail}

\makeatother
\begin{document}
  The included pdf is on pages
  \pageref{start-example-image-duck.pdf} -- \pageref{stop-example-image-duck.pdf}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% adding the blank page before including %%
  \afterpage{\blankpage}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
  \includepdf[pages={1-2,4},pagecommand={}]{example-image-duck.pdf}
\end{document}

But, unfortunately, \pageref{start-example-image-duck.pdf} does not yield the correct page number. More precisely, it gives the correct page number decreased by one.
On the other hand, everything works fine upon removing the blank page.
How to fix this?
Log file:
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.26 (TeX Live 2024) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2024.3.26)  28 JUN 2024 17:34
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 file:line:error style messages enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**Senza-nome.tex
(./Senza-nome.tex
LaTeX2e <2023-11-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2024-02-20>
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2023/05/17 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size12.clo
File: size12.clo 2023/05/17 v1.4n Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count188
\c@section=\count189
\c@subsection=\count190
\c@subsubsection=\count191
\c@paragraph=\count192
\c@subparagraph=\count193
\c@figure=\count194
\c@table=\count195
\abovecaptionskip=\skip48
\belowcaptionskip=\skip49
\bibindent=\dimen140
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/afterpage.sty
Package: afterpage 2023/07/04 v1.08 After-Page Package (DPC)
\AP@output=\toks17
\AP@partial=\box51
\AP@footins=\box52
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pdfpages/pdfpages.sty
Package: pdfpages 2024/01/21 v0.5y Insert pages of external PDF documents (AM)

(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty
Package: ifthen 2022/04/13 v1.1d Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/calc.sty
Package: calc 2023/07/08 v4.3 Infix arithmetic (KKT,FJ)
\calc@Acount=\count196
\calc@Bcount=\count197
\calc@Adimen=\dimen141
\calc@Bdimen=\dimen142
\calc@Askip=\skip50
\calc@Bskip=\skip51
LaTeX Info: Redefining \setlength on input line 80.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \addtolength on input line 81.
\calc@Ccount=\count198
\calc@Cskip=\skip52
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/eso-pic/eso-pic.sty
Package: eso-pic 2023/05/03 v3.0c eso-pic (RN)
\ESO@tempdima=\dimen143
\ESO@tempdimb=\dimen144

(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2022/05/29 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks18
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
Package: xcolor 2023/11/15 v3.01 LaTeX color extensions (UK)

(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg
File: color.cfg 2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
)
Package xcolor Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 274.

(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/pdftex.def
File: pdftex.def 2022/09/22 v1.2b Graphics/color driver for pdftex
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/mathcolor.ltx)
Package xcolor Info: Model `cmy' substituted by `cmy0' on input line 1350.
Package xcolor Info: Model `hsb' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1354.
Package xcolor Info: Model `RGB' extended on input line 1366.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HTML' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1368.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Hsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1369.
Package xcolor Info: Model `tHsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1370.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HSB' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1371.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Gray' substituted by `gray' on input line 1372.
Package xcolor Info: Model `wave' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1373.
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
Package: graphicx 2021/09/16 v1.2d Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
Package: graphics 2022/03/10 v1.4e Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty
Package: trig 2021/08/11 v1.11 sin cos tan (DPC)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg
File: graphics.cfg 2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 107.
)
\Gin@req@height=\dimen145
\Gin@req@width=\dimen146
)
\AM@pagewidth=\dimen147
\AM@pageheight=\dimen148
\AM@fboxrule=\dimen149

(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pdfpages/pppdftex.def
File: pppdftex.def 2024/01/21 v0.5y Pdfpages driver for pdfTeX (AM)
)
\pdfpages@includegraphics@status=\count199
\AM@pagebox=\box53
\AM@global@opts=\toks19
\AM@pagecnt=\count266
\AM@toc@title=\toks20
\AM@lof@heading=\toks21
\c@AM@survey=\count267
\AM@templatesizebox=\box54
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty
Package: etoolbox 2020/10/05 v2.5k e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
\etb@tempcnta=\count268
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.def
File: l3backend-pdftex.def 2024-02-20 L3 backend support: PDF output (pdfTeX)
\l__color_backend_stack_int=\count269
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box55
)
(./Senza-nome.aux)
\openout1 = `Senza-nome.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 25.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 25.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 25.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 25.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 25.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 25.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 25.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 25.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 25.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 25.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 25.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 25.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 25.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 25.

(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
\scratchcounter=\count270
\scratchdimen=\dimen150
\scratchbox=\box56
\nofMPsegments=\count271
\nofMParguments=\count272
\everyMPshowfont=\toks22
\MPscratchCnt=\count273
\MPscratchDim=\dimen151
\MPnumerator=\count274
\makeMPintoPDFobject=\count275
\everyMPtoPDFconversion=\toks23
) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/epstopdf-pkg/epstopdf-base.sty
Package: epstopdf-base 2020-01-24 v2.11 Base part for package epstopdf
Package epstopdf-base Info: Redefining graphics rule for `.eps' on input line 4
85.

(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg
File: epstopdf-sys.cfg 2010/07/13 v1.3 Configuration of (r)epstopdf for TeX Liv
e
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pdflscape/pdflscape.sty
Package: pdflscape 2022-10-27 v0.13 Display of landscape pages in PDF

(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pdflscape/pdflscape-nometadata.st
y
Package: pdflscape-nometadata 2022-10-28 v0.13 Display of landscape pages in PD
F (HO)
 (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty
Package: iftex 2022/02/03 v1.0f TeX engine tests
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/lscape.sty
Package: lscape 2020/05/28 v3.02 Landscape Pages (DPC)
)
Package pdflscape Info: Auto-detected driver: pdftex on input line 81.
))
<example-image-duck.pdf, id=1, 184.55048pt x 114.2107pt>
File: example-image-duck.pdf Graphic file (type pdf)
<use example-image-duck.pdf>
Package pdftex.def Info: example-image-duck.pdf  used on input line 32.
(pdftex.def)             Requested size: 184.55002pt x 114.2104pt.
File: example-image-duck.pdf Graphic file (type pdf)
<use example-image-duck.pdf>
Package pdftex.def Info: example-image-duck.pdf  used on input line 32.
(pdftex.def)             Requested size: 184.55002pt x 114.2104pt.
File: example-image-duck.pdf Graphic file (type pdf)
<use example-image-duck.pdf>
Package pdftex.def Info: example-image-duck.pdf  used on input line 32.
(pdftex.def)             Requested size: 184.55002pt x 114.2104pt.
<example-image-duck.pdf, id=5, page=1, 184.55048pt x 114.2107pt>
File: example-image-duck.pdf Graphic file (type pdf)
<use example-image-duck.pdf, page 1>
Package pdftex.def Info: example-image-duck.pdf , page1 used on input line 32.
(pdftex.def)             Requested size: 184.55002pt x 114.2104pt.
File: example-image-duck.pdf Graphic file (type pdf)
<use example-image-duck.pdf, page 1>
Package pdftex.def Info: example-image-duck.pdf , page1 used on input line 32.
(pdftex.def)             Requested size: 616.12886pt x 381.29677pt.
 [1

{/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] [2

]
File: example-image-duck.pdf Graphic file (type pdf)
<use example-image-duck.pdf, page 1>
Package pdftex.def Info: example-image-duck.pdf , page1 used on input line 32.
(pdftex.def)             Requested size: 616.12886pt x 381.29677pt.
File: example-image-duck.pdf Graphic file (type pdf)
<use example-image-duck.pdf, page 1>
Package pdftex.def Info: example-image-duck.pdf , page1 used on input line 32.
(pdftex.def)             Requested size: 616.12886pt x 381.29677pt.
File: example-image-duck.pdf Graphic file (type pdf)
<use example-image-duck.pdf, page 1>
Package pdftex.def Info: example-image-duck.pdf , page1 used on input line 32.
(pdftex.def)             Requested size: 616.12886pt x 381.29677pt.
 [3

 </usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/duckuments/example-image-duck.pd
f>]
<example-image-duck.pdf, id=20, page=2, 184.55048pt x 114.2107pt>
File: example-image-duck.pdf Graphic file (type pdf)
<use example-image-duck.pdf, page 2>
Package pdftex.def Info: example-image-duck.pdf , page2 used on input line 32.
(pdftex.def)             Requested size: 616.12886pt x 381.29677pt.
File: example-image-duck.pdf Graphic file (type pdf)
<use example-image-duck.pdf, page 2>
Package pdftex.def Info: example-image-duck.pdf , page2 used on input line 32.
(pdftex.def)             Requested size: 616.12886pt x 381.29677pt.
File: example-image-duck.pdf Graphic file (type pdf)
<use example-image-duck.pdf, page 2>
Package pdftex.def Info: example-image-duck.pdf , page2 used on input line 32.
(pdftex.def)             Requested size: 616.12886pt x 381.29677pt.

[4

 </usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/duckuments/example-image-duck.pd
f>]
<example-image-duck.pdf, id=24, page=4, 184.55048pt x 114.2107pt>
File: example-image-duck.pdf Graphic file (type pdf)
<use example-image-duck.pdf, page 4>
Package pdftex.def Info: example-image-duck.pdf , page4 used on input line 32.
(pdftex.def)             Requested size: 616.12886pt x 381.29677pt.
File: example-image-duck.pdf Graphic file (type pdf)
<use example-image-duck.pdf, page 4>
Package pdftex.def Info: example-image-duck.pdf , page4 used on input line 32.
(pdftex.def)             Requested size: 616.12886pt x 381.29677pt.
File: example-image-duck.pdf Graphic file (type pdf)
<use example-image-duck.pdf, page 4>
Package pdftex.def Info: example-image-duck.pdf , page4 used on input line 32.
(pdftex.def)             Requested size: 616.12886pt x 381.29677pt.
 [5

 </usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/duckuments/example-image-duck.pd
f>] (./Senza-nome.aux)
 ***********
LaTeX2e <2023-11-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2024-02-20>
 ***********
 ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 3070 strings out of 474116
 49215 string characters out of 5743682
 1929187 words of memory out of 5000000
 25428 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 558367 words of font info for 37 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 72i,17n,79p,13593b,433s stack positions out of 10000i,1000n,20000p,200000b,200000s
</usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr12.pfb>

Output written on Senza-nome.pdf (5 pages, 21709 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 34 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 16 compressed objects within 1 object stream
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 36 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)


well I get the correct page reference 3 – 5. But I don't understand at all why you are using afterpage. Why not a simple \clearpage\null\thispagestyle{empty}\clearpage?  (you don't need an external document for the example, you can simply use e.g. example-image-duck)

Thank you. I just copied and pasted a command to create a blank page that I found on the web, didn't know about this simpler alternative.

I also get pages 3-5. In the comment you left on my answer, you also had a command to decrease the page number by 1, but it wasn't possible to tell if that command was commented out or not. But, if you have that in your actual source and it is not commented, it would decrease page numbers by 1. (But not just the first one.)

With \clearpage\null\thispagestyle{empty}\clearpage I get pages 3-5, but not with \afterpage{\blankpage} as explained above, that's weird

I get 3-5 with \afterpage{\blankpage}.

I get 2-5 with \afterpage{\blankpage}, instead... very curious fact. Using TeXLive 2024 on Mac OS Sonoma

If you get 2-5 when you compile the example in your question, post your log file.

I appended the content of the log file at the end of my question above (using example-image-duck instead of kantlipsum).

That uses a different .tex file. What code exactly did you compile? Something using example-image-duck, but what? To compare my log with yours, I need to know exactly the code you used.

Yes, sorry: I forgot to say that I just used example-image-duck.pdf instead of kantlipsum.pdf as an example PDF to include. No other change.

If I substitute example-image-duck for kantlipsum, I still get 3-5. Hang on ...

Check for updates. There was a pdftex where afterpage was broken.

@UlrikeFischer https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/65869414#65869414

@FrancescoB Do you still see this problem? In chat, you said you got the right references when you deleted the .aux and recompiled. That sounded odd to me: you shouldn't have to delete the file to get the right references, but it sounded as if you'd resolved the issue somehow.

Yes, I did, thank you. Don't know if it was due to updates (thanks @UlrikeFischer) or to deleting the .aux file; in any case, I used \clearpage\null\thispagestyle{empty}\clearpage and it did the work.
